# ios core plot increase CPTPlotSymbol clickable area

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot, increment, clickable

I am using core plot library for showing Scatter plot in my app. I am creating CPTPlotSymbol like this :-

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
plotSymbol.fill          = [CPTFill fillWithColor:blueColor];
plotSymbol.lineStyle     = symbolLineStyle;
plotSymbol.size          = CGSizeMake(5.0 , 5.0);
```

Then graph point are looking like this.

[image]

I am trying to click these points on iphone device but I am not able to click them easily.

I want to keep points size as it is now and want to increase the clickable area only. Is it possible with core plot library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` property on the scatter plot. This increases the size of the tappable zone around each plot symbol.